# Syntax Highlighting: match N lines surrounding cursor

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to write some `syn` commands to select a certain number of lines on either side of the current cursor line, so that, for instance, there is always a "view port" of 3 lines with specific highlighting where ever I put the cursor.

I think if it's possible, it will involve the `\%#` atom, but I'm not sure how to actually use it to do the match.

So basically, I want to do this:

```
:syn match ViewPort <SOME-PATTERN-PROBABLY-INVOLVING-%#>
:hi ViewPort guibg=pink
```

For instance. The effect I'm looking for is very similar to `cursorline`, but with more than just the current line, say the current line plus the one above and the one below (or two above and two below, etc).

My end goal is to have a "secure" syntax such that most of the text has the same foreground and background color so that it is effectively invisible, and just have one small window of the text "visible" at one time.

Comment: Could you show us what you have, tell us what you think it should do and exlain how it fails?

Comment: No. I have nothing other than what I already put, which is essentially just an idea that `\%#` should be involved. I know how to write syntax files, I know regex in general, and I know how to highlight, but I'm after something very specific and don't know how to do it. As far as "how it fails": it fails by not selecting lines based on the position of the cursor. I know your response is the mantra here on SO and it's very appropriate in some cases, but I think my question is valid and sufficient as is. Whether or not anyone can answer it is obviously another matter.

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why isn't `:set cursorline` enough for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'cursorcolumn'` option was introduced because the previous attempts at emulating such with syntax / `:match` were slow and inadequate. Your requirement looks like a super-sized cursorline, and therefore is likely to fail.

In particular, the `\%#` atom for the current cursor position is **not** automatically updated, as described in its help:

> WARNING: When the cursor is moved after the pattern was used, the
>     result becomes invalid.  Vim doesn't automatically update the matches.
>     This is especially relevant for syntax highlighting and 'hlsearch'.

So you would have to use `:autocmd CursorMoved`, and it would probably be **very** slow.

Comment: Yeh, I'm not holding out a lot of hope for this, but you're right, a super-sized cursorline is exactly what I'm looking for (although with nested syntax highlighting within it, which I don't think cursorline does).

Comment: Actually, `cursorline` does do nested highlighting, so a super-sized cursorline is exactly what I want.

Comment: Have a look at Dr.Chips [HiCurLine plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#HICURLINE), which implements cursorline in Vimscript. You may be able to modify it, but, as I said, it won't be perfect. To get that, you'd have to modify Vim's sources itself.